# QLineEdit rounded corners

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Is there a way to round the corners of a QLineEdit widget? If not, is there a similar widget I could do this to?

**Visual Meaning:**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use *StyleSheets* to set styles of Qt components just like you would use them in making a website. You can set a stylesheet in two ways: in your application's code, or in QtDesiner.

To do it in *QtDesiner* (which is most convenient), right-click on the component which you have placed on the form, and press "Edit StyleSheet" (or maybe "Change Stylesheet", sorry, my Qt is not it English, so I'm not sure about the exact name of the option). A window will open that will let you edit the element's style sheet.

It is very convenient because it has some useful options like adding resources or colors or fonts right there, and you just need to press a couple of buttons to set the option you need through the GUI without the need to type or even to know CSS syntax.

From the *code*, you can do it like this (example):

```
SomeComponent->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { border-radius: 5px; }");
```

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/stylesheet-reference.html) is the documentation about the stylesheets.

Comment: Hi, since you mentioned stylesheet as in website, do all the styles available in websites work? Like say `:active`, 'transition', `margin`, etc?

Answer (score 5):

Use stylesheets. From http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html:

```
QLineEdit {
 border: 2px solid gray;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Also, you can always override paintEvent if you want to get your hands dirty.

Comment: Paint sounds fun.  Pros? Cons?

Comment: @BrandonClark, pros are that you can make a component look like _anytihng_ you can imagine. Cons are that you will need to handle the drawing yourself.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial on how to override paintEvent: http://zetcode.com/gui/qt4/painting/. But I would go with stylesheets if yhe only thing you need is rounded corners